# shouldChangeCharactersInRange is not called for keyboard suggestions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a keyboard and I pick suggestions of Chinese characters from it but it doesn't call shouldChangeCharactersInRange method on tapping suggestions. It is only called if user types in text field.

I have searched for this question and seems like no one has given any proper answer for this one.

I found following workaround that resolves my issue.

**EDITED:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textChanged:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:textField];


- (void)textChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
  {
     [self textField:textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.stringXYZ.length) replacementString:self.stringXYZ.text];
  }
```

Comment: I've got this problem too, and i can input even if the text if out of range. I guess this is a bug of ios. If you want to limit the text length, i think there is a workaround, to do the limitation in the `editingChanged` action.

Comment: @MudOnTire I have workaround and it works fine. You can check my edit.